# What causes my ISP to stop giving IP Address randomly?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, modem, isp

I run a pfSense firewall. Out of the blue one night I lost my IP lease and I didn't get a new one. I even tried using a backup router to get the IP and I didn't get anything among many other troubleshooting issues.

I left the modem off all night and I finally was able to get an IP 6 hours later. Is this normal for DHCP IPs? Should I get a static? I've had this happen a few times and it's really annoying. I don't spam getting new IP addresses either. Normally I keep the same IP for very long periods of time.

Can this just be a crappy modem issue as well in bridge mode? It's a Westell.

Comment: It's likely crappiness of your ISP, not the modem.  If that's the case then yes get a static IP.

Comment: A DHCP IP address lease will expire after a time determined by your ISP. If the modem is off it will be unable to renew the lease and the IP address will be free to be reassigned to another client. Many ISPs are in the difficult position of having a shortage of IP addresses and are unable to obtain more. The ISP may offer a static IP but you will be paying a premium price for it.

Comment: It's likely that the ISP had their DHCP server go down. It happens to the best of ISPs sometimes.